# c++ thread speed test, am I doing right?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have such simple program, which increments every element of vector by 1 in 8 threads (I have 8 cores on my PC). But it only accelerates the program 2.8 times, what I am doing wrong or multithreading works not so fast?

> Cost is 599 milliseconds
>   800000000
>   Cost is 1697 milliseconds
>   800000000

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

void test(int n, int k)
{
    std::vector<int> data(n * k, 0);
    std::vector<std::thread> threads(n);
    auto functor = [] (int *begin, int *end) {
        for (int *p = begin; p != end; p++) {
            *p = *p + 1;
        }
    };

    auto begin = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        threads[i] = std::thread(std::bind(functor, data.data() + i * k, data.data() + (i + 1) * k));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        threads[i].join();
    }
    auto now = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    auto elapsed = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(now - begin);
    std::cout << "Cost is " << elapsed .count() << " milliseconds" << std::endl;

    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n * k; i++) {
        sum += data[i];
    }
    std::cerr << sum << std::endl;
}

void stupid_test(int n, int k)
{
    std::vector<int> data(n * k, 0);
    std::vector<std::thread> threads(n);
    auto functor = [] (int *begin, int *end) {
        for (int *p = begin; p != end; p++) {
            *p = *p + 1;
        }
    };

    auto begin = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        functor(data.data() + i * k, data.data() + (i + 1) * k);
    }
    auto now = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    auto elapsed = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(now - begin);
    std::cout << "Cost is " << elapsed .count() << " milliseconds" << std::endl;

    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n * k; i++) {
        sum += data[i];
    }
    std::cerr << sum << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    test(8, 100000000);
    stupid_test(8, 100000000);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ***But it only accelerates the program 2.8 times, what I am doing wrong or multithreading works not so fast?*** Don't expect a linear speed up. There is overhead to create the threads and to join and all cores share the same memory bandwith.

Comment: Obligatory: you compiled with optimizations on, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "8 cores" is probably 4 hyperthreaded cores for 8 execution units.  This has a maximum of ~5.2x  (4 cores with ~30% max speed up with the hyperthreading).  If you run only 4 threads the speed probably won't change much.

Since some of the CPU resources (cache) and memory are shared among all the cores, the limiting speed here is the speed of the linear memory access from the 8 executing threads.  Even only doing 2 threads won't give a 2x speedup.